# Insert html element into a previously dynamically inserted element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my first question here, I've been looking for an small clue on many researches but didn't found any piece of answer, hope it's not a silly thing.

I'll try to be straight: I'm working on a website dealing with xml files (data is stored in an array then displayed and fully editable).

Until now and despite some troubles I figured out, everything works fine.

I loop on my array to get all the required string then create jQuery object (such as `$("<input id='xxx' value='yyy' />")` that I appendTo a specific div).

At first start, I have an empty #insertXml div (written in my html).
One my xml files parsed and my array ready, I dynamcically create a #content div appended to my #insertXml, then for each index I'll have its key written in a #keyInput" div (dynamic insert, only once), then 1st value in a #lang1 div (still dynamic insert), 2nd in #lang2 div, etc.

lang1, lang2, etc are variables, so it's written:

```
 $("<input .../>").appendTo("#"+langN);
```

where langN changes on each loop.

Everything works FINE!... at 1st display :/

The trouble is, when I'm using my function that creates new data.
I work first on a modal window, to retrieve user values through the listener function, then pass it to another function that pushes it in my array.
I debugged it, that works, my array is correctly updated.

Then I want to simply refresh my page, so I try, the same way I did previously for my whole data, to append a few inputs.

It works then correctly on my #keyInput div, but NOT on my #lang divs !?!?!
No matter how I try (even forgetting jQuery and using html document.xxx functions), no way.

While debugging, all my variables are OK, it just does nothing when doing the "appendTo", except once for the keyInput div.

I tried then to remove the #content div and relaunch the whole displayInit() method (heavy operation but, just to see) and same damn problem: only the #keyInput is correctly refreshed.

The only thing I've read that may be interesting, is that dynamically created elements (through script) are not registered in the DOM, so it can't be found.
BUT in that case, none of my display attempts should work, so?

In advance, THANK YOU very much for taking care about my nightmare.

Attached: my html + JS function.[my DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kelrJ.jpg)

```js
function displayInsert() {

    var firstLang = stripXmlExtension(paths[0]); // same keys on every language, so we grab the 1st one
    var lastKeyIndex = mapXml[firstLang].key.length - 1;
    var keyToInsert = mapXml[firstLang].key[lastKeyIndex]; // == last insertion

    var inputKey = "<input size=35 type=text id=k" + lastKeyIndex + " value=" + stripHTML(keyToInsert.replace(/ /g, " ")) + " readonly />";
    // while appending tag to the HTML content page, we add a dblclick listener that will morph the input into a textarea when double dblclicked
    $(inputKey).css("margin-bottom", "15px").dblclick(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        tempEditId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(".modal-body").html("<textarea cols='65' rows='10' id='txt" + $(this).attr('id') + "'>" + $(this).val() + "</textarea>");
        $("#modalEdit #btn-correct").css("display", "none");
        $("#modalEdit").modal({backdrop: "static"});
    }).appendTo("#keyInput");


    for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        var lang = stripXmlExtension(paths[i]);
        var lastValueIndex = mapXml[lang].value.length - 1;
        var valueToInsert = mapXml[lang].value[lastValueIndex]; // == last insertion


        var inputValue = "<input size=35 type=text id=" + lang + "---" + lastValueIndex + " value=" + stripHTML(valueToInsert.replace(/ /g, " ")) + " readonly />";
        // while appending tag to the HTML content page, we add a dblclick listener that will morph the input into a textarea when double clicked
        $(inputValue).css("margin-bottom", "15px").dblclick(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            tempEditId = $(this).attr('id');
            $(".modal-body").html("<textarea cols='65' rows='10' id='txt" + $(this).attr('id') + "'>" + $(this).val() + "</textarea>");
            $("#modalEdit #btn-correct").css("display", "none");
            $("#modalEdit").modal({backdrop: "static"});
        }).appendTo("#" + lang);

    }

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the _shortest code_ necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, I'm ashamed.

My problem came from an input generated in a modal window that took the same id that was duplicated...
I was hoping it would be a little more complicated ^^

Solved!